# Generate n columns in dataframe based on mutiple values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created dataframe like this from a table

```
df = spark.sql("select * from test")  # it is having 2 columns id and name
df2 = df.groupby('id').agg(collect_list('name')
df2.show()
```

```
|id|name|
|44038:4572|[0032477212299451]|
|44038:5439|[00324772, 0032477, 003247, 00324]|
|44038:4429|[0032477212299308]|
```

Until here it's correct, for one id I can store multiple names (values).
Now when I try to create dynamic columns into dataframe based on values, it is not working.

```
df3 = df2.select([df2.id] + [df2.name[i] for i in range (length)])
```

**Output:**

```
|id |name[0]|
|44038:4572|0032477212299451|
|44038:5439|00324772|
|44038:4429|032477212299308|
```

**Expected output in dataframe:**

```
|id|name[0]|name[1]|name[2]|name[3]|
|44038:4572|0032477212299451|null|null|null|
|44038:5439|00324772|0032477|003247|0034|
|44038:4429|032477212299308|null|null|null|
```

And then have to replace `null` with `0`.

Comment: Same pivot i am trying with steaming data but seems getting below error:-
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
code:-

dfnew2 = dfnew1.select(f.col("Newcolumn"), f.col("Newcolumn1"))
dfnew3 = dfnew2.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Newcolumn").orderBy(F.desc("Newcolumn1")))).groupBy("Newcolumn").pivot('rn').agg(F.first('Newcolumn1'))


dfnew2 is streaming source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off doing `pivot` instead of `collect_list`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = (df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.desc('name'))))
         .groupBy('id')
         .pivot('rn')
         .agg(F.first('name'))
         .fillna("0")
      )

df2.show()
+----------+----------------+-------+------+-----+
|        id|               1|      2|     3|    4|
+----------+----------------+-------+------+-----+
|44038:4572|0032477212299451|      0|     0|    0|
|44038:5439|        00324772|0032477|003247|00324|
|44038:4429|0032477212299308|      0|     0|    0|
+----------+----------------+-------+------+-----+
```

If you want pretty column names, you can do

```
df3 = df2.toDF('id', *[f'name{i}' for i in range(len(df2.columns) - 1)])
df3.show()
+----------+----------------+-------+------+-----+
|        id|           name0|  name1| name2|name3|
+----------+----------------+-------+------+-----+
|44038:4572|0032477212299451|      0|     0|    0|
|44038:5439|        00324772|0032477|003247|00324|
|44038:4429|0032477212299308|      0|     0|    0|
+----------+----------------+-------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Same pivot i am trying with steaming data but seems getting below error:- Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();; code:- dfnew2 = dfnew1.select(f.col("Newcolumn"), f.col("Newcolumn1")) dfnew3 = dfnew2.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Newcolumn").orderBy(F.desc("Newcolumn1")))).groupBy("Newcolumn").pivot('rn').agg(F.first('Newcolumn1')) dfnew2 is streaming source

Comment: I'm not familiar with streaming. Would you mind opening another question so that others can help you? @AbhishekVij